# ignoring some text in Xcode's "Export for localization"

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I am using the "Export for Localization" menu option in Xcode to generate XLIFF files for our translators.

Many of these labels will be changed at runtime populated with data.  Is there a way to mark these labels, buttons, etc as not needing to be translated so that they do not make it to the XLIFF files?  Right now I'm keeping the labels as "Label".  Is there a way to mark it as non-translatable and could put in sample data that would be changed at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked a few times before, and the answer was no: see for example [Lou Franco's question here (with a Radar ID he has opened with Apple)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407282/marking-some-xib-storyboard-strings-as-not-localizable) and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338720/xcode-dont-localize-specific-strings). Unless Apple changes this behaviour in XCode you will have to live with workarounds like using a labelling mechanism or adding `translate="no"` attributes to your non-translatable `<trans-unit>` elements in XLIFF.